# Perform service interception with Fabric3

Tags: soa, sca, apache-tuscany

I´m doing a POC with Fabric3 (*Service Component Architecture Framework*) and would like to know if there is some native way to proceed interception in my Services? Something like `@Interceptors` of EJB or a Filter of a web environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on your requirements. One is via binding handlers and the other is by writing a custom interceptor.

We'd be happy to help you further and walk you through this. Could you post a brief description of your requirements to the user list? Instructions for doing so can be found on our support page: http://fabric3.org/support.html

Thanks,
Jim